# Opencart 2.2 - new custome theme not available in the admin panel

Tags: themes, opencart, opencart2.x

I just followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-part-two--cms-21865)  to create a custom new theme for my localhost opencart 2.2 installation. I followed the following instructions from the tutorial :

***Let's create a new directory, named mycustomtheme underneath catalog/view/theme.   .....   Furthermore, you need to create three more directories within the mycustomtheme  directory: image, stylesheet, and templates***.

Then I navigated to Admin->System->Settings and clicked on the 'Edit' button of the default store and in the subsequent page expected to get the custom theme in the 'Theme' dropdown but only the 'Default Store theme ' was there.

The tutorial tells that I am supposed to get a 'Template' dropdown there and I found a 'Theme' dropdown instead due to version change I think.

But how to activate the new theme then ?

Comment: Copy paste the `default` theme and paste is the the same location and rename it to `mycustomtheme` and see do you get the theme option in settings?

Comment: It's not coming...

Answer (score 9):

To change a theme on Opencart 2.2.0.0, follow below setting:

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Go to Extension > Themes > Edit
3. Select your theme for Theme Directory option
4. Click on save to activate your new theme.

Comment: Theme is enabled in extension>Themes>Edit...but its still not coming in Admin->System->Settings >store>Edit> Themes

Comment: Here is the helpful answer for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097531/why-is-opencart-2-3-custom-theme-not-showing/40140155#40140155

Answer (score 2):

In opencart 2.2 you need to go into the Admin->Extensions->Themes

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bit late to answer but it can be helpful to others.

In OpenCart 2.3.0.2 creating a custom theme is little complex , i have already answered it here , you can check this link

[Why is OpenCart 2.3 custom theme not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097531/why-is-opencart-2-3-custom-theme-not-showing/42242052#42242052)

or can find this blog

http://undefined.gr/site/2016/10/09/custom-opencart-2-3-0-2-theme/

Answer (score 1):

In Open  Cart version:2.2
"Admin->Extensions->themes" You can Select your theme.Enable That theme.
After that go to "Extensions->Modules->Theme Control panel",choose your theme and click on insert data,then all data added successfully.